# Allow rust struct entry to be of multiple types

Tags: rust, struct, enums

Forgive me if this is basic, I am new to rust.  I am trying to create some `struct`s that mimic an external API.  In the external api, there is a property that could be either a number or a string.  In typescript, I could do something like this:

```
interface ApiParams {
  thing: string | number;
}
```

In rust I'd want to do the same with the `thing` property inside my `struct`, but I can't find any such method, or examples of a dynamic types, or questions that quite match what I'm trying to do here.  Allowing for a dynamic type seems to go against the very typesafe nature of rust, but I still need to allow this within my api and database to match an external api.

I tried this:

```rust
pub enum Thing {
    CouldBeANumber(u8),
    CouldBeAString(String),
}

struct ExternalApiThing {
  thing: Thing
}
```

But when I post to my API, I get this kind of error

`Json deserialize error: unknown variant 'the string that was posted', expected 'CouldBeANumber' or 'CouldBeAString' at line 1 column 1921`

Clearly I'm not understanding how to make an enum such that I can use any number or any string.

How does one achieve such a thing in rust?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Serde here, then by default, it will serialize the enum as a JSON Object, so what you'll see is this:

```
{"thing":{"CouldBeANumber":2}}
{"thing":{"CouldBeAString":"boo"}}%
```

Clearly that's not what you want, so you want to declare `Thing` as untagged:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Thing {
    CouldBeANumber(u8),
    CouldBeAString(String),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ExternalApiThing {
  thing: Thing
}

fn main() {
    let thing1 = ExternalApiThing { thing: Thing::CouldBeANumber(2) };
    let thing2 = ExternalApiThing { thing: Thing::CouldBeAString("boo".into()) };
    let _ = serde_json::to_writer(std::io::stdout(), &thing1);
    println!();
    let _ = serde_json::to_writer(std::io::stdout(), &thing2);
}
```

Then what you get is this:

```
{"thing":2}
{"thing":"boo"}
```

…which is what you were hoping for.  [The docs outline several other ways](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html) you can serialize an enum, plus a lot of other options that you can use to control things as you like.  I consult it frequently.